# how to optimize the views in CakePHP v2

Tags: cakephp

I have many view like Shops, Categories, Products, Toppings....
And using the hardcoded Model names very often. Sometimes singular ot plural. like in the *`Shop's index.ctp`*

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Shop'), array( 'action' => 'add'));?></li>
</ul>

<div class="page-header">
    <h1><?php echo __('Shops'); ?></h1>
</div>
```

AND

```
<td><?php echo $shop['Shop']['id']; ?>
<td><?php echo $shop['Shop']['name']; ?>
<td><?php echo $shop['Shop']['street']; ?>
...
```

Is there a better way to dynamically use the model names?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can add `$myshop = $shop['Shop'];` at the top of your code so you can use `$myshop['id']` but thats pretty much it. It's not weird to use variables where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to you could do the same that Controllers have, $this->modelClass property contains the model name.

In the controller

```
$this->set('modelClass', $this->modelClass);
```

In the view:

```
echo $shop[$modelClass]['field'];
```